# Alternative to .siblings()

Tags: jquery, html

What do I use as an alternative to the `.siblings()` method in jQuery to traverse over divs of a particular class but in separate div containers?For something like this to work:

HTML:

```
<div id="container1">
   <div id="1"></div>
</div> 

<div id="container2">
   <div id="2"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#1').addClass('selected');

$('.selected').on('click',function() {
    alert('hi');
});

$('#2').addClass('selectable');

$('.selectable').on('click',function() {
   $(this).addClass('selected')
          .removeClass('selectable')
          .siblings('.selected')
          .off('click');
});
```

Comment: Anyone want to write a `.cousins()` plugin? (ie, shares a grandparent)

Comment: How about `.friends()`?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot jQey Tribbiani?

Comment: @Jamiec,Beetroot-Beetroot,StuperUser Hahahaha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this might help:

```
$('.selectable').on('click',function() {
   $(this).addClass('selected')
          .removeClass('selectable')
          .parent()
          .siblings()
          .children()
          .off('click');
 });
```

Comment: +1 This does work! http://jsfiddle.net/93Cvx/2/ But I'm open to more solutions before I select one.

Comment: Oh ok I'll select this.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd code this a different way:

**EDIT:**

```
$('#1').addClass('selected');
$('#2').addClass('selectable');

var $outerContainer = $('#container1').parent();
$outerContainer.on('click','.selected,.selectable', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is(".selected")) {
        alert('hi');
    } else {        // .selectable
        $('.selected', $outerContainer)
            .removeClass('selected')
            .addClass('selectable');
        $(event.target)
            .addClass('selected')
            .removeClass('selectable');
    }
});
```

Here's a [**link to jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/Eu8Gj/3/)

Comment: Ah no this makes the .selectable element alert on click. http://jsfiddle.net/93Cvx/3/

Comment: @Ronophobia, ahh, yes, I had been neglecting the fact that the propagated event would come last. See my edited post.